# How to get Queries out of FOR Loops?

Tags: trigger, query

Still new to Triggers and am having a difficult time understanding Maps, lists and queries outside of my loops under the Trigger.isUpdate portion of my Trigger.  Can anyone help.

```
trigger createCaseComment2 on Support_Comment__c (after insert, after update) {

    Id Id;
    Id ccId;
    string commentBody = null;

    List<Support_Comment__c> supportCommentsToUpdate = new List<Support_Comment__c>();
    List<CaseComment> caseCommentsToInsert = new List<CaseComment>();
    List<CaseComment> caseCommentsToUpdate = new List<CaseComment>();
    List<CaseComment> caseCommentsToDelete = new List<CaseComment>();

    Map<Id, CaseComment> supportCommentIdToCaseComments = new Map<Id, CaseComment>();

        if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            Id = newSupportComment.Id;

            System.debug('The newSupportComment Id = ' + Id);
            if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true){

                CaseComment cComment = new CaseComment(ParentId = newSupportComment.Case__c, CommentBody = newSupportComment.Comment__c, IsPublished = TRUE);
                caseCommentsToInsert.add(cComment);

                supportCommentIdToCaseComments.put(newSupportComment.Id, cComment);
            }
        }
        insert caseCommentsToInsert;

        for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true){

                ccId = supportCommentIdToCaseComments.get(newSupportComment.Id).Id;
                System.debug('The new standard Comment Id = ' + ccId);

                Support_Comment__c supComsToUpdate = new Support_Comment__c(Id = newSupportComment.Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId);
                supportCommentsToUpdate.add(supComsToUpdate);
            }
        }
        update supportCommentsToUpdate;
    }

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            Id = newSupportComment.Id;

            System.debug('The newSupportComment Id = ' + Id);
            if (stoprecurssion.runonce()){
                if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true){

                    CaseComment cComment = new CaseComment(ParentId = newSupportComment.Case__c, CommentBody = newSupportComment.Comment__c, IsPublished = TRUE);
                    caseCommentsToInsert.add(cComment);

                    supportCommentIdToCaseComments.put(newSupportComment.Id, cComment);
                }
            }
        }
        insert caseCommentsToInsert;

        for (Support_Comment__c newSupportComment : Trigger.new) {
            if (newSupportComment.Comment__c != null && newSupportComment.Community_User__c == 'Standard User' && newSupportComment.Public__c == true && Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c != null){

                ccId = supportCommentIdToCaseComments.get(newSupportComment.Id).Id;
                System.debug('The new standard Comment Id = ' + ccId);

                Support_Comment__c supComsToUpdate = new Support_Comment__c(Id = newSupportComment.Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId);
                supportCommentsToUpdate.add(supComsToUpdate);
            }
        }

        update supportCommentsToUpdate;
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Support_Comment__c updatedSupComPrivate : Trigger.new) {
            Id = updatedSupComPrivate.Id;
            Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(Id);
            String oldComBody = oldSupportComment.Comment__c;
            Boolean isPub = oldSupportComment.Public__c;
            String cComId = oldSupportComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c;

                if (oldSupportComment.Public__c == FALSE && updatedSupComPrivate.Public__c == TRUE && updatedSupComPrivate.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c == null) {

                CaseComment cCommentAdd = new CaseComment(ParentId = updatedSupComPrivate.Case__c, CommentBody = updatedSupComPrivate.Comment__c, IsPublished = TRUE);
                caseCommentsToInsert.add(cCommentAdd);

                supportCommentIdToCaseComments.put(updatedSupComPrivate.Id, cCommentAdd);
                }
            }
            insert caseCommentsToInsert;

            for (Support_Comment__c updatedSupComPrivate : Trigger.new) {
                if (updatedSupComPrivate.Public__c == TRUE && updatedSupComPrivate.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c == null) {

                    ccId = supportCommentIdToCaseComments.get(updatedSupComPrivate.Id).Id;
                    System.debug('The new standard Comment Id = ' + ccId);

                    Support_Comment__c supComsToUpdate = new Support_Comment__c(Id = updatedSupComPrivate.Id, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c = ccId);
                    supportCommentsToUpdate.add(supComsToUpdate);
                }
            }
            update supportCommentsToUpdate;

        for (Support_Comment__c updatedSupportCommentPublic : Trigger.new) {
            Id = updatedSupportCommentPublic.Id;
            Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(Id);
            String oldComBody = oldSupportComment.Comment__c;
            Boolean isPub = oldSupportComment.Public__c;
            String cComId = oldSupportComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c;

           Support_Comment__c updatedComment = [SELECT Id, Comment__c, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c, public__c FROM Support_Comment__c WHERE Id =:oldSupportComment.Id];

            if (updatedComment.Public__c == TRUE && oldSupportComment.Comment__c == oldComBody && oldSupportComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c != null) { 

               CaseComment cCommentUpdate = [SELECT Id, ParentId, CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId =:oldSupportComment.Case__c AND Id =:cComId];
                if (cCommentUpdate.Id == cComId) {

                    cCommentUpdate.CommentBody = updatedComment.Comment__c;
                    caseCommentsToUpdate.add(cCommentUpdate);
                }
            }
        }
        update caseCommentsToUpdate;

        for (Support_Comment__c supportCommentNowPrivate : Trigger.new) {
            Id = supportCommentNowPrivate.Id;
            Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(Id);
            String oldComBody = oldSupportComment.Comment__c;
            Boolean isPub = oldSupportComment.Public__c;
            String cComId = oldSupportComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c;

            Support_Comment__c privateComment = [SELECT Id, Comment__c, Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c, public__c FROM Support_Comment__c WHERE Id =:oldSupportComment.Id];

            if (privateComment.Public__c == FALSE && oldSupportComment.Public__c == TRUE && oldSupportComment.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c != null) {                
                CaseComment cCommentRemove = [SELECT Id, ParentId, CommentBody FROM CaseComment WHERE ParentId =:oldSupportComment.Case__c AND Id =:cComId];

                    if (cCommentRemove.Id == cComId) {

                        caseCommentsToDelete.add(cCommentRemove);
                    }
            }
        }
        delete caseCommentsToDelete;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any queries...

Comment: Looks like you or someone has already worked to bulkify the inserts and updates by using lists. Do you have a specific problem? The general idea is to collect data in lists and maps so that multiple records can be inserted or updated at once. That counts as just 1 operation whatever the number of records whereas if you insert or update each record in turn you can easily exceed the governor limit of 150. For queries, again you query many at a time and put the result in a list or map so it can be referenced later in the trigger without further queries.

Comment: Sorry, that was not the whole trigger.  I have updated the code to include the portion with the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your already have the version of the data before the update (`updatedSupportCommentPublic`) and after the update (`oldSupportComment`) with just this code so no query is required for that part:

```
for (Support_Comment__c updatedSupportCommentPublic : Trigger.new) {
    Id = updatedSupportCommentPublic.Id;
    Support_Comment__c oldSupportComment = Trigger.oldMap.get(Id);
```

To move a query out of a loop, collect the Id values in the loop:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<id>();
for (Support_Comment__c sc : Trigger.new) {
    ...
    ids.add(sc.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c);
    ...
}
```

and then query after the loop into a map (using this handy constructor that sets the key to the Id and the value to the SObject):

```
Map<Id, CaseComment> m = new Map<Id, CaseComment>([
        select Id, CommentBody from CaseComment where Id = :ids
        ]);
```

Then run the same loop again and you can get the values from the map:

```
CaseComment[] updates = new CaseComment[] {};
for (Support_Comment__c sc : Trigger.new) {
    ...
    CaseComment cc = m.get(sc.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c);
    if (cc.CommentBody != sc.Comment__c) {
        updates.add(new CaseComment(Id = cc.Id, CommentBody = sc.Comment__c));
    }
    ...
}
update updates;
```

Another approach is to run a relationship query that gets both the related objects together (see [relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)) where you can avoid the map and just access the related object through a `__r` field.

Or in your case you could avoid the query altogether if typically the comments were changing so you were happy to always update:

```
CaseComment[] updates = new CaseComment[] {};
for (Support_Comment__c sc : Trigger.new) {
    ...
    updates.add(new CaseComment(
            Id = sc.Standard_Case_Comment_Id__c,
            CommentBody = sc.Comment__c
            ));
    ...
}
update updates;
```